# intent crashing app

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent

I'm using Intents, to pass an array from one Activity to another in Android.
That's the code in one class.

```
Button los = (Button) findViewById(R.id.starten);
        int[] a = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49 };
        shuffleArray(a);

        final Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this, melderfragen.class);
        intent.putExtra("schuffledNumbers", a);


        los.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Here is the code in the recieving class.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        int[] questions = intent.getIntArrayExtra("shuffledNumbers");
```

So far it works fine. The app crashes however, when I want to acces a number from the array like so:

```
int Fragenummer = questions[2];
```

What's wrong with my code?
I hope I didn't ask a duplicate question, but I haven't found a solution here so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending `schuffledNumbers` and trying to read `shuffledNumbers`. Note the extra **c** in the first one.

Its a good pratice to use constants to prevent this kind of situation. So you could define:

```
public static final String EXTRA_SHUFFLED_NUMBERS = "shuffled_numbers";
```

and use such constant at both places.

Comment: +1 yes, this approach should practise every. Also code as more cleaner and safer.

Comment: Oh, man, a typo -.- Thanks for pointing that out and also for the tip regarding the constants.